# Problems with scanf and or fgets program cuttoff

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, fgets

I am trying to write a code that reads in a integer using scanf and then asks the user if they would like to enter another by entering "yes" or "no". I get no errors when I compile but when I run the program it asks for the number, displays it as it should, ask to continue and then promptly closes without taking any input.

```
int main()
   {
        int *data=malloc(1*sizeof(int));
        if(data==NULL)
        {
                printf("out of memory");
                exit(1);
        }

        char *yc="yes";
        char uinput[20];

        int numinput;
        printf("enter a number \n");
        scanf("%d",&numinput);
        data[0]=numinput;
        printf("you entered %d \n",numinput);
        printf("would you like to enter another # ?");
        fgets(uinput,sizeof(uinput),stdin);

        int count=0;
        int n,i;
        int comp=strncmp(uinput,yc,1);
        while(comp==0)
        {
                n=sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
                count=count+1;
                data=(int*)realloc(data,n+1);
                printf("enter another number:\n");
                scanf("%d",&numinput);
                data[n+1]=numinput;
                printf("the numbers are:\n");
                for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
                {
                        printf("%d\n",data[i]);
                }
                printf("would you like to enter another # ?");
                fgets(uinput,sizeof(uinput),stdin);



        }
                printf("Goodbye!\n");


        return(0);
}
```

This is what happens when I run the program

```
./vector_play.out
enter a number 
6
you entered 6 
would you like to enter another # ?Goodbye!
```

I am not sure why it is immediately exiting any help would be great.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&numinput);` leaves `'\n'` in `stdin` for `fgets()` to consume.  Avoid using `scanf()` and `fget()` together - drop `scanf()`.

Comment: You can use a `do...while` loop to avoid same code twice. As for your problem, you can use `scanf("%d%*c",&numinput);` instead of `scanf("%d",&numinput);`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that after `numinput` has been read using the code in

```
scanf("%d",&numinput);
```

the newline character is still left in the input stream. The call to `fgets` reads the newline as a complete line and returns without waiting for any further input.

You need to add a line to ignore the rest of the input stream. You can use `fgets` for that purpose too.

```
scanf("%d",&numinput);
fgets(uinput,sizeof(uinput),stdin); // Read and ignore   
printf("you entered %d \n",numinput);
printf("would you like to enter another # ?");
fgets(uinput,sizeof(uinput),stdin);
```